# PHP 5.3.3 wrecked up on CentOS 6.5 (32bit) after upgrade to 5.4 and downgrade to 5.3.3

Tags: php, centos6.5, upgrade, php53

please help me solve this php version problem.
I had Centos 6.5 (32bit) and php 5.3.3 pre-installed on it, right before I decided to wreck it!
The need to upgrade was this warning:

```
Warning:  DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in ...
```

and I found that it needs to be, at least 5.3.6 to work. Using [this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502656/upgrading-php-on-centos-6-5-final), I upgraded to php 54w like this:

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
yum remove php-common       # Need to remove this, otherwise it conflicts
yum install php54w
php --version               # Verify version has been upgraded
```

but, after that I experienced some conflicts, and tried to remove the php and re-install it, and now I can not phpmyadmin opens nothing and `SimpleXmlElement` returns some errors like:

```
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 2: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in ...
```

or

```
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding() in
```

or

```
PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^ in
```

or

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'
```

, which I had not before this (with the pre-installed 5.3.3).

Guys, Please help me with this. I googled alot and each stack-like article pushes me to variety of totaly different commands. I am realy with it :(

---

**Problem Solved**

---

Finally the problem solved!
A friend of mine, suggested installing `php-mbstring` like this:

```
sudo yum install php-mbstring
```

and atfer that the problem was solved (and phpmyadmin works fine again) and I am back at the state that have this warning:

```
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in ...
```

and now I need to upgrade at least to php 5.3.6. I will ask it in a seperate thread, after some googling.
I realy appreciate helps from "Nomad" and sorry for the insufficient reputaion to upvote your helpful answer.

Comment: If this in a web server (e.g. Apache): Did you restart it?

Comment: So have you tried to get back to a clean `5.3.3`?

Comment: Yes I restarted the apache server multiple times (after each change) and also removed php and installed it (if this is the right way to get back to 5.3.3)

Comment: @SvW is there any known way to totaly roll-back to the pre-installed php collection and then upgrade to (at least 5.3.6) newer version? please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
yum remove php
yum install php
yum install php-simplexml
```

Comment: as I mentioned, I exactly tried this. But it seems to have some problems as I now recieve odd errors for `SimpleXmlElement` which I had not whit the pre-installed php5.3.3

Comment: You didn't say you used these commands specifically. What is the output when you run them? You are being a bit vague...

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the commands, but I realy think some libraries are not installed with them, as I have some errors on `SimpleXmlElement` which I did not with the pre-installed version.

Comment: Check my answer again, for php-simplexml installation.

Comment: Just saying "you have some errors on SimpleXml" is very vague. How do you get the errors? If you want better help, provide information.

Comment: Thanks for good comment. I will add it, but I think this was obviouse problem with php libraries.

Comment: I tried `yum install php-simplexml` too, but it says it has already this in php-common and nothing installed

Comment: So this is a problem with phpmyadmin and not PHP. Try to upgrade/reinstall phpmyadmin?